# Is this the right solution for the following floating point numerical?

Tags: floating-point, computer-science, cpu-architecture

**Question :**

*Represent the number (+465) base 10 as a floating point number (binary) with 24-bits the normalized fraction, mantissa has 16-bits and exponent has 8-bits ?*

**Answer :**

1) Convert the 465 to binary which is equal to 111010001

2) Normalize the binary number which is 1.11010001 * 2 ^ 8

3) Add bias of 127 and convert it to binary which is 1.11010001 * 2 ^ ( 8 + 127 ) => 1.11010001 * 2 ^ 10000111 ( binary representation of 135 )

4) Combining all together like this :  10000111 ( exponent of 8-bits ) 11010001 00000000 ( mantissa of 16-bits )

Note : I have not included the sign bit because the question doesn't mention it.

Comment: You should do some research before posting homework. For example, [this converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) and [this other converter](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=052054053) answer your question and are the first two Google results for "float to bin".

Comment: @MargaretBloom this was not a homework and i was confused plus here teachers don't know anything and google didn't help.

Comment: @MargaretBloom and also i was not sure if its the right way to do it "your conversion sites" just convert they don't give explain. so you should first analysis the question first then you could down vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your result looks correct, though you still have to add zero bits for the less significant bits of your mantissa to get a total of 16; right now you've shown only 8.

Comment: Like this "11010001 0000000" ? one more thing if i have an exponent of say 300 what should be the bias value for that  in single precision ?  btw thanks for you kindness sir or mam whatever you are ;)

Comment: Also do i have to include sign bit or not in this particular question ?

Comment: @Ahti: An exponent of 300 can't be represented in single precision. You only get values from roughly -127 to +127 (or so) in binary, which works out to about -38 to +38 in decimal. As for sign bit...hard to guess what your instructor might want.

Comment: okay that means i can have at max an exponent of -38 or +38 in single precision and if i have more than that say -39 or +39 or greater than that then i should use double precision ?

Comment: Yeah,  double would be the obvious choice.

Comment: Thanks alot for you kindness :D